# show status of multiple fields with LIKE and OR

Tags: mysql, operators, status

I'm trying to show the status of two variables in mysql

```sql
$ sudo mysql -e "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment' OR LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'' at line 1
$ sudo mysql -e "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment' OR STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'' at line 1
$ sudo mysql -e "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment' OR SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'' at line 1
$
```

Comment: Hint - [INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-global_status-and-session_status-tables/).

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54953/mysql-fetch-multiple-global-status-and-system-variable-in-a-single-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add `WHERE`

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name IN ('x', 'y')
```

or

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE 'x' or variable_name LIKE 'y'
```